# Using Upload in Express Nodejs with Multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I want to create a middleware and instantiate in my "server.js" file the file upload option..

That done, I configured my server.js as follows.

```
"use strict";

import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import helmet from 'helmet';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import {
  i18n
} from './i18n';
import routes from './routes';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({dest: "../public/storage/app/uploads"});
const path = require('path');
dotenv.config();

global.logger = function (args) {  
  console.log("-------------------------------------------------");  
  for (var arg = 0; arg < arguments.length; ++arg) {
    var arr = arguments[arg];
    console.log(`${arr}`);
  }
  console.log("-------------------------------------------------");
}

class App {
  constructor() {
    this.express = express();
    
    this.middlewares();
    this.routes();
        
    // Method 1
    const nDate = new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', {
      timeZone: process.env.TZ
    });

    const server = this.express.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
      console.log(`Welcome to Marketplace => PORT ${process.env.PORT || 3000} -> ${nDate}`);
    });
  }

  middlewares() {
    this.express.use(cors({
      origin: process.env.CORS_ORIGIN || '*'
    }));
    this.express.use(helmet());
    this.express.use(morgan('dev'));
    this.express.use(express.json());
    this.express.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    // for parsing application/json
    this.express.use(bodyParser.json());
    // for parsing application/xwww-
    this.express.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
      extended: true
    }));
    //form-urlencoded
    // for parsing multipart/form-data
    this.express.use(upload.array());    

    let appExpress = this.express;
    i18n.init({
      appExpress
    });
  }

  routes() {
    this.express.use(routes);
  }
}
export default new App().express;
```

My file routes.js

```
import { Router } from 'express';
let routeUsers = Router();
routeUsers.put("/:token", Users.update.bind(Users));
```

And my frontend request via axios send the data using FormData, my payload example is:

```
email: testes@email.com
website: mkmm
twitter: twotter
instagram: instagram
files[image_cover]: (binary)
files[image_profile]: (binary)
```

The problem is being when I'm submitting a form that contains an input file.

I have the following error return

```
MulterError: Unexpected field
    at wrappedFileFilter (C:\Projetos\marketplace\backend\node_modules\multer\index.js:40:19)
    at Busboy.<anonymous> (C:\Projetos\marketplace\backend\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:115:7)
    at Busboy.emit (node:events:526:28)
    at Busboy.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at Busboy.emit (C:\Projetos\marketplace\backend\node_modules\busboy\lib\main.js:38:33)
    at PartStream.<anonymous> (C:\Projetos\marketplace\backend\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:213:13)
    at PartStream.emit (node:events:526:28)
    at PartStream.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at HeaderParser.<anonymous> (C:\Projetos\marketplace\backend\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:51:16)
    at HeaderParser.emit (node:events:526:28)
```

How can I do to fix this?

Comment: `this.express.use(upload.array('files'));`: .array(fieldname[, maxCount])
Accept an array of files, all with the name fieldname.

Comment: @traynor but in this case that you said I can only send files right? if I also need to send other parameters, as in the example, I have a payload in formdata that has both normal inputs and the input file.

Comment: I did the test you mentioned (```this.express.use(upload.array("files")) ```), but it didn't work.
When I send the formdata with the file it returns the error that is attached.

Comment: the problem is most likely that there is a mismatch between fieldname on the server and frontend, it must be the same. you're probably using `.append('files[]', file)` on the frontend, so try changing that to `.append('files', file, 'image_cover')`

Comment: try these examples, and change fieldname accordingly: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append#examples

Comment: you can also send other fields as well in formData, they will be in `req.body`, and files in `req.files`

Comment: When you call `multer` call `any` function also on the result. like `var upload = multer({}).any()`, This way _multer_ will parse additional _formData_ fields.